# Is it possible to make the imports within `__init__.py` visible for python `help()` command?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

Suppose I have a module:

`mymodule/example.py`:

```
def add_one(number):
    return number + 1
```

And `mymodule/__init__.py`:

```
from .example import *

foo = "FOO"

def bar():
    return 1
```

Now I see the function at the root of `mymodule`:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.add_one(3)
4
>>> mymodule.foo
'FOO'
```

Also, I see imported `add_one` through `dir` along with `example`:

```
>>> dir(mymodule)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'add_one', 'bar', 'example', 'foo']
```

But when I type `help(mymodule)` I see only `example`, `foo` and `bar`, but not the imported `add_one`:

```
Help on package mymodule:

NAME
    mymodule

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    example

FUNCTIONS
    bar()

DATA
    foo = 'FOO'
```

But I can call `add_one()` as the root function of `mymodule`. Is it possible to see it in help as root function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code of help() ([docmodule under pydoc.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pydoc.py#L791))

```py
        for key, value in inspect.getmembers(object, inspect.isroutine):
            # if __all__ exists, believe it.  Otherwise use old heuristic.
            if (all is not None or
                inspect.isbuiltin(value) or inspect.getmodule(value) is object):
                if visiblename(key, all, object):
                    funcs.append((key, value))
```

The important part is `inspect.getmodule(value) is object)`, this is where values that are not directly part of the object itself are dropped

You can add this line

```py
__all__ = ['bar', 'add_one', 'FOO']
```

to your `__init__.py` file, this way the help function will make sure to include these objects in help

Keep in mind that if you do this anything you don't include in this list will not be included

Comment: Thanks! I thought that `__all__` just defines what will be imported when I do `from mymodule import *`. Now I see that it also affects the logic, how `help()` is composed. Ok.